# Start a new multiprocessing.pool() process for each one that dies

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm using a python api for a proprietary software to run numerical simulations. I need to do quite a few so have tried to speed things up using multiprocessing.pool() to run simulations in parallel. The simulations are independent and the function passed to multiprosessing.pool() returns nothing but the simulation results are saved to disk. As far as I understand this should be similar to opening X no of terminals and running a call to the API from each.

Using multiprocessing starts off well, I can see all processors running at 100% which is expected for the simulations. However after a while the processes seem to die. Eventually I end up with no active processes but still simulations that have not started. I think that the problem is that the API is sometimes a a little buggy. Certain errors cause python kernel to crash. I think this likely what is happening with my multiprocessing.pool().

Is there a way that I can add a new process for each one that dies so that there will always be processes in the pool? For now I can run the individual simulations that give problems manually.

Below is a minimum working example but I am not sure how to reproduce an error that causes the kernel to crash so it is not of much use.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import time

def test_function(a,b):
    "Takes in two variables to justify starmap, pause,return nothing"
    print(f'running case {a}')
    ' api(a,b) - Runs a simulation and saves output to disk'
    'include error that "randomly" crashes python console/process'
    time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    case_names = list(range(60))
    b = 'b'
    
    inputs = [(a,b) for a in case_names]  #All the inputs in order needed by run_wdi

    
    
    start_time = time.time()
    
    # no_processes = cpu_count()
    no_processes = min(cpu_count(),len(inputs))
    
    print(f"Using {no_processes} processes on {cpu_count()} cpu's")
    
    # with Pool(processes=no_processes) as pool:
    with Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.starmap(test_function, inputs)
    
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f'Total time {end_time-start_time}')
```

Comment: Do you *know* that this simulation program sometimes crashes the Python interpreter, or are you just guessing?  You might spend a lot of effort solving the wrong problem.  If the crashes happen often enough to worry about, I would call that a "major catastrophic API defect" rather than "sometimes a little buggy."  How do you know that the count of active processes drops to zero after some time?  Also, did you try setting maxtasksperchild=1 in the Pool() constructor call?

Comment: Hi @PaulCornelius, thanks for your response. In the multiprocessing example I am guessing that the simulation program is crashing the python interpreter. I'm not sure how to return details from the child processes.  However, when I run the API "normally" without multiprocessing the interpreter sometimes crashes. I work in spyder so can see all the variables are gone and I need to restart the python interpreter. It seems to happen when there is an error in the input file which is why I can deal with these cases individually for now but Ill also raise this with the API vendor separately.

Comment: Hi @PaulCornelius. I have updated the script to use Pool(maxtasksperchild=1). Printing the start of each case I can now see that each case starts and using os.getpid() i can see each one has a unique pid no. I cant tell if the processes that die get replaced or just hang around doing nothing. However, unless there is an easy way to check this I think i must spend my time trying to get the vendor to fix the API. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't run your script myself but the docs suggest that the Pool will launch a new process each time.  I think you are doing the best thing by fixing the API - good luck to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that commented/provided feedback. It looks like the problem is linked to a buggy API so I am going to park this for now.